# Why the border is applied and delete?

Tags: javascript

***Im giving a border to a div, but if i set the border, it is removed automatically, why?***

PD: I know if i set the border in the last call of the function it will work, but i want to know why this happen.

```js
var padding = 0, e = document.getElementById("box");
function box(){
 if(padding < 80) { padding ++;
 e.setAttribute("style","padding:"+padding+"px");
 setTimeout(()=>{box();},50);
 }
 if(padding%7 === 0) { // 
 e.style.border = "2px solid purple";
 }
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",box);
```

```css
#box {
width: 50px;height:50px;background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
```

Answer (score 2):

`e.setAttribute("style","...")` overrides the `style.border` that you set elsewhere (since it resets `style` completely).

You should only use `style.* = "..."`.

Or, better yet, use CSS animations instead.

Comment: I thought the same, but background color isnt removed.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian yes, that is because background color is not a part of the style attribute of the element in question. It is applied separately to `#box`

Comment: mmm ,i thought that all works like a fnal style ,thanks.